# receiving udp packets from a specific client

Tags: c, tcp, udp, ip, port

I am trying to implement UDP Server with "accept" function like the one in TCP. That because I need to keep one channel for each client. My question is how to let the UDP socket receiving Daata from a specific client (specific client's ip and port)?

TCP uses a main Socket (within a thread) that receives the request from a client. Once a request from a client commes, the main socket opens another socket for communicating with that client (within another thread). To implement this Mechanisem, the ability to bind socket to receive packets from a specific client must be available. This ability what I am asking for. How can i reimplement the "Accept" function for UDP Sockets ? where (as I know) it is not possible to bind Socket for receiving from a specific client. My Question is how to make it possible ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), describe what it currently does and then describe what you need it to do instead that it isn't doing.

Comment: post was edited, hopfully it is now better. thank you

Comment: No, please don't just describe code in words. It is almost never precise enough. Please construct a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the context and problem. Your question is still too unclear. General info that *may* be relevant: UDP is a connection-less protocol. A single UDP socket can receive from multiple different clients. Don't need to `accept` as that is only relevant for connection based protocols.

Comment: 'the ability to bind socket to receive packets from a specific client must be available' yeah, and you can do that with a user-space list of IP/port/userContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To implement this mechanism, the ability to bind socket to receive packets from a specific client must be available.

`bind` does not specify a **remote** client which can connect, but specifies the **local** address where data should be sent to. This is in UDP the same as in TCP. It is not possible in TCP to `accept` only a specific client, but one can `accept` a connection and then simply close it if it is the wrong client.

With UDP one can `bind` a socket to receive data on a local IP and port. One can additionally `connect` the UDP socket to get only data from a specific client IP and port. Note that this is different from `connect` in TCP: in TCP it actively establishes a connection (i.e. packets get exchanged during TCP handshake) whereas in UDP it only sets the peers address on the socket.

It is not possible though to `connect` to a specific client IP only. `connect` needs both IP and port. If the client source port is not known upfront, one can create an unconnected but bound UDP socket, call `recvfrom` on it and then `connect` the socket to the clients IP,port as returned by `recvfrom` (or create a new bound and connected socket) if it is the expected client.